# I can't figure out this error message (ArrayList BankAccount code)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to practice for my test in Java tomorrow, but I can't figure out what is going on.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BankAccount
{
    public static void BankAccount(double x)
    {
        ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        BankAccount ted = new BankAccount(400);
        BankAcconut bob = new BankAccount(300);
        BackAccount carol = new BankAccount(500);
        accounts.add(new BankAccount(300));
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error message that says "constructor BankAccount in class BankAccount cannot be applied to given terms; required: no arguments; found:int;

I know this is small cheese compared to what you guys are doing, but I'm new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is fairly clear. You don't have a constructor on your class that takes an `int`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Please look at the error message again. There is a default no-arg constructor included in your code automatically. There is no int constructor. Hence the error.

Comment: A static method named the same as the class is a bad idea. Also, what's the point of the parameter `x`; it's never used.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't supplied any constructors, so [Java creates a default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), with no arguments, that does nothing.

Supply a one-argument constructor that takes an `int` that you are supplying.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any explicit constructor for `BankAccount`. You appear to be confusing your `static` method called `BankAccount` (don't do that; it's asking to get confused) with a constructor. You probably mean to do something like this:

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Then put that other code that's constructing `BankAccount` objects somewhere else, like `main`. (It's okay to put `main` on this same class, but it's essentially irrelevant where it goes. What matters is that you need a constructor for the class you're trying to construct.)

Comment: Wow! I went to the bathroom and came back to find 7 people already helped me out! I can't thank you enough. My code works great now. Hope I didn't come across as stupid

Answer (score 0):

Your class `BankAccount` needs a constructor that looks like this.

```
public BankAccount(int funds){
    this.funds = funds;
}
```

This assumes that class `BankAccount` has an attribute called `funds`, which could represent, for example, the available funds.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void BankAccount(double x)
```

There are no static constructors in Java. Thats why it doesn't get regocnized as a constructor. Just delete the `static` and the `void` as pointed out below.

Because there is no constructor defined automatically a constructor is added on compile time that has no arguments and because "your" constructor does not match the constructor you want to call you get this error.

Comment: ...and the void. Also, this method should not be a constructor, otherwise there would be a constructor-infinite-loop

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have not defined `BankAccount` constructor that accepts an `int`. Modify your code as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BankAccount
{
    // public constructor of BankAccount class
    public BankAccount(int value){
        // do something here with value
    }
    public static void BankAccount(double x)
    {
        ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        BankAccount ted = new BankAccount(400);
        BankAcconut bob = new BankAccount(300);
        BackAccount carol = new BankAccount(500);
        accounts.add(new BankAccount(300));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BankAccount {

private double balance = 0.0;

public BankAccount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

public BankAccount(double d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    balance = d;
}

public static void main(String[] args) //BankAccount(double x)
{
    ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    BankAccount ted = new BankAccount(400.0);
    BankAccount bob = new BankAccount(300.0);
    BankAccount carol = new BankAccount(500);
    accounts.add(new BankAccount(300));
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add "D" after the numbers; This will make make it a double.

So this

> BankAccount ted = new BankAccount(400);

becomes

> BankAccount ted = new BankAccount(400D);

Comment: Think about it for a second.